# Jquery - .load() Post & Array - How Access Array Data

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following code to load a PHP & pass Data to it:

```
  var data = [];

  // Gender Males
  if($('#searchSimpleSubOptionMalesActiveIMG').is(':visible')) {
      data['male'] = 'yes';
  }else{
      data['male'] = 'no';
  }


  $('#mainContainerDIV #searchresults #'+type).load('scripts/php/searchresults.php', data, function() {
```

The searchresults.php file loads file but I'm unsure how to access the information in the data[] array.

I've tried the following:

```
print_r($_POST);

echo $_POST['male'];
```

There must be another trick to this... Any advice... thankyou!

Comment: when in doubt use console.log()

Comment: have you tried `GET`, `$_GET['male']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with jQuery.load: use $_GET[....]

OR 
send a post request like:

```
$.post( url, {"male":yes,"id":"..."},function( res ) {
                                     target.empty().html(res);

                                }
                        ).error(function(data) {
                                // ....
                        });
```

OR

submit the form in a way like this:

```
$(".DATA-FORM").each(function(){
            $(this).unbind();
            $(this).submit(function(event) {
                    var _form = $( this ), url = _form.attr( 'action' );
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var target_id = _form.find( 'input[name="UI-POST-ACTION-RESPONSE-TARGET"]' ).val();
                    var target = $("#"+target_id);

                    $.post( url, _form.serialize(),
                            function( res ) {
                                 target.empty().html(res);

                            }
                    ).error(function(data) {
                            // ....
                    });
            });

    });
```

if you use post, you cann access the submited data using `$_POST["..."]`

Answer (score 2):

`jQuery.load` initializes an HTTP GET request, and not POST. So you should use:

```
$_GET['male']
```